# Is Kubernetes a PaaS?

Tags: cloud

PaaS assumes that the platform has to provide an environment to write applications and deploy them. Can we categorize Kubernetes as PaaS?

Comment: This is a valid question, just not one really for this website.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer without going through the details. The final scope of Kubernetes is to provide a way to deploy containers and organize them (for instance: make sure they are the number required, make sure they are exposed through a service, make sure they are talking together...). We may call this a Caas. Writing, building and consuming container image with applications in it is a standard process. Therefore, to my understanding, the answer is yes. For simple deployment (like mysql wordpress [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/mysql-wordpress-pd)) it could be straightforward (near to turnkey). And of course become a more complex beast for bigger projects.

Comment: I agree with you. Kubernetes is a CaaS but you can build PaaS with it.